# undefined symbols for architecture when using boost for iOS

Tags: c++, boost, ios7, xcode5.1

I am building boost for ios, mac and sims using the script found here. I am on xcode 5.1.1, mac osx 10.9.2 and trying to build for ios7 devices.

https://github.com/mgrebenets/boost-xcode5-iosx

It builds fine but when I integrate it into my xcode (ios) project and try to use it.

I get these errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"boost::locale::base_message_format<char>::id", referenced from:
boost::locale::basic_message<char>::write(std::__1::locale const&, int, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&)
```

but when I use the file command on the library file itself, it shows this:

```
file boost.framework/boost
boost.framework/boost: Mach-O universal binary with 5 architectures
boost.framework/boost (for architecture armv7): current ar archive random library
boost.framework/boost (for architecture armv7s):    current ar archive random library
boost.framework/boost (for architecture i386):  current ar archive random library
boost.framework/boost (for architecture x86_64):    current ar archive random library
boost.framework/boost (for architecture cputype (16777228) cpusubtype (0)): current ar archive
```

Has anyone run into this problem when trying to build boost for ios devices like this one?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Update your project settings so that it builds with `libc++` (see [Undefined symbols link error](https://github.com/mgrebenets/boost-xcode5-iosx#undefined-symbols-link-error)).

Comment: Ya I tried but I still get the same error as above

Comment: You should build Boost (and any other C++ code) with clang/llvm and its `libc++` library.